# WinRT: Show upper and lower AppBar independently

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, appbar

I need to provide the functionality that a user opens the upper AppBar by swiping down
but keeping the lower AppBar closed.

Is this possible in Windows Store Apps? Can anybody point me to the right solution or give
a few lines of code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.topappbar.aspx

Use a `Page.TopAppBar` but not a `Page.BottomAppBar`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have to keep a lower AppBar. The lower swipe should open the lower AppBar. The upper swipe the upper AppBar.

Comment: That's not supported and you shouldn't try to do it. What about keyboard shortcut or right mouse click? What would these do?1

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using the CustomAppBar from the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/).

This allows you to override the events for showing / hiding correctly.